# How to specify a custom Repair functionality for an MSI created using WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created an MSI which installs a Visual Studio 2012 extension package (VSIX) and a couple of other components. There's no option to select which features get installed ( I don't want to give user the choice). All the features get installed by default. However, when I try to repair the MSI ( either from control panel or from MSI itself), it throws up an error. How do I customize this Repair functionality? If I cannot customize, how do I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you said what the error actually was. However, the most likely reason is that you have a custom action that is running again (maybe because of the condition you used on it) and it's failing because it's not checking that it was run before, or it uses a property value that no longer is valid - for example INSTALLDIR is not preserved after the install unless you preserve it somewhere.

Comment: This is was because it was trying to re-install the VSIX, but failed because it was already installed. Got this from the log file. How do i customize this behavior? A code snippet would really help.

Comment: The log says: 
MSI (s) (14:DC) [09:37:45:134]: Product: xxxx -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action vimDFB2F9AEFFD9086DFB0CA1225BECFC4F, location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe, command: /q  /skuName:Pro /skuVersion:11.0 "C:\Program Files\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx.vsix" /admin

Comment: Yes, that program is crashing, you are trying to re-run that installer program.

Comment: Is there no way to disable the repair functionality altogether?

Comment: No. It's part of the architecture, and there's no way to stop somebody right-clicking your MSI file and choosing repair.